# How to solve the error Too many }'s

Tags: errors

I had given the code as below, but getting the error too many's}

```
   \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.2in,%
            left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,%
            footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[sfdefault,light]{roboto}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\definecolor{tuftsblue}{rgb}{0.28, 0.57, 0.81}
\definecolor{cobalt}{rgb}{0.0, 0.28, 0.67}
\begin{document}

flushleft
{\color{cobalt}
\Large{contents}\\
}
\centering
\raggedright
 This is my first document……………………………………............................................................... 3\\
 \vspace{3mm}
 This is my first document…………………………………………………………........................................... 4\\
  \vspace{3mm}
 This is my first document……………………………………………...….......................…..........................5\\
  \vspace{3mm}
  This is my first document………………………………………………….....….......................…..................8\\
  \vspace{3mm}
 This is my first document…………………………………………………................................................... 9\\
  \vspace{3mm}
 This is my first document…………………….……………………………………………....................................28\\
  \vspace{3mm}
 This is my first document………………………………………………….....................................................69\\
 \newpage
                    }
\flushleft
{\color{cobalt}
\Large{xxx}
}
\begin{figure}[!hbt]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=4in]{Italy.png}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}[!hbt]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
 dates : & 4th, Dec 2019 \\\hline
 Site : & x ,y \\\hline
 Capacity: & xxx \\\hline
 type: & fixedi \\\hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `}` in line 36 does not have an `{` equivalent. Removing it should make the code compilable.

Comment: Are you suere you want to build the table of contents manually? Why not use the usual `\tableofcontents` command in combination with `\section`?

Comment: Please explain the purpose of `\flushleft
{\color{cobalt}
\Large{xxx}
}` Do you use it to add a something like a pagenumber or text in a page header? If so, take a look at the `fancyhdr` package that you already load.

Comment: `\usepackage{xcolor}
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}` can be summarized ot `\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}`.

Comment: the purpose of \flushleft {\color{cobalt} \Large{xxx} } is to add the heading in the new page, the heaading will come in the place of xxx

Comment: What kind of heading? The title of a chapter or section or some contents that is placed in the page header?

Comment: Title of a chapter

Comment: And can please help me to use the \table of contents command and how to align it properly on right side, if I aligned in latex also it is not aligning in pdf

Comment: you have `\usepackage{fontspec}` so can not be using latex+dvips so remove `[dvips]` also you should remove the `\\ `  especially the one after `\end{table}` which can not do anything useful. Also size commands do not take an argument, so `\Large{xxx}` should be `\Large xxx`

Comment: `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.2in,%
            left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,%
            footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[sfdefault,light]{roboto}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove demo option in your document.
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{xxx}
\begin{figure}[!hbt]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=4in]{Italy.png}
\end{figure}
\section{section title}
\subsection{subsection title}
\end{document}`  should serve as a place to start from.

Comment: You can build upon the example in my previous comment (compile it twice to get the toc) by adding some clarifications: How many sectioning levels do you need? Do you want each chapter/section to start on a new page? How exactly should the section headers look like?...