# How to give the page number starting from 2 and how to align the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq7BL.png)How to give the page number starting form two and need to align the table of contents.. I had give the code as

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.2in,%
            left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,%
            footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\LARGE{contents}\\
summary.............................3\\
\vspace{3mm}
Secound page.......................4\\
\vspace{3mm}
Third page...........................5\\

\newpage 

\LARGE{summary}

This is my first document

\newpage

\LARGE{chapter}

\end{document}
```

I got the document like this need to start the page number from 2 and align the toc
[image]

after trying the code that you had given I got the result like this
[image]

I need the document like this, only the heading should be in the top of the page and the contents page should have the respective heading page number
[image]

Comment: Please do not try to make a manual table of contents. latex can do that for you. With an automatically generated table of contents there is no need to worry about alignment and page numbers being up to date.

Comment: See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/547332/how-to-solve-the-error-too-many-s#comment1382492_547332

Answer (score 1):

Do not try to produce a manually created table of contents. With latex you can get an automatically generated table fo contents using the `\tableofcontents` command. For automatically numbered chapter, section, subsection... titles you can use `\chapter` , `\section`, `\subsection`...:

[image]

Compile the following document twice:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.2in,%
            left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,%
            footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{summary}

This is my first document

\chapter{chapter heading}

\section{a section heading}

\subsection{a subsection}

your text

\end{document}
```

If this alignment/layout does not suit your needs, it can be of course customized.

Comment: i had tried the code but the result is wat I got is not the proper one

Comment: The table of contents are not displaying in the front page and in every page the word chapter is having along with the numbers, I need not to have the word chapter in the report in all pages

Comment: I had added snap shot of the page what I got in the top , please have look at that

Comment: To get the table of contents to be filled with the chapters and sections, compile your document twice.

Comment: Regarding the chapter headings: How exactly should they look like? Do you want each chapter to start on a new page? Please clarify that. Probably a sketch of the desired output would also be helpful.

Comment: Probably `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{summary}
This is my first document
\section{chapter heading}
\subsection{a section heading}
\subsubsection{a subsection}
your text
\end{document}` is closer to the desired output?

Comment: I had added the screenshot of the document in my question page as how I needed, I need the document like the third image, the only heading of the page shoud be there at top of page  chapter number and word chapter should not be there, can you please look at the third image